# How to create border-bottom equally between two lines

Tags: css, list, border

I have a  with:

```
.menuoptions {
    height:30px;
    width:225px;
    color:#666;
    line-height:40px;
    font-weight:bold;
    padding-left:10px;
    margin-top:-10px;
    border-bottom:solid 1px #FF0000;

}
```

but I want the bottom line to be equally between each list, not directly below the word.
is this possible?

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/959Bm/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

CSS:

```
.menuoptions li:not(:last-child){
    border-bottom:solid 1px #FF0000;        
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/959Bm/4/)

Comment: Thank you @Hiral works perfect. I didn't need the last child though as I wanted a line under the last list